# How to restore nuget packages?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

i've been working on a ASP.Net mvc5 project and been using TFS as my Version control. Been going great up until now when I formated my computer to Windows 10.

I have a couple of references that didn't work, so I need to restore them. 
I know I can use the following nuget command `Update-Package –reinstall` how ever using that doesn't work as I want it to. It does not restore all the packages such as `System.Web.Mvc` How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: I did, how ever reinstalling all packages did not work I had to make a new project and than manually drag the new packages over to the old project and replace those files..

Comment: I don't remember from the top of my head what nuget told me, but it were something similar to that it could not find the assembly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update or re-install your .net Framework.